# How can I get a data from socket and make a protobuf file?

Tags: swift, sockets, protocol-buffers

How to receive a file from socket in swift and converting it to swift protobuf?

First of all I'm using blue socket from IBM .

I try to receive the size of the protobuf in String format, then convert it to int and then I open a buffer of the size I get from server.

The problem is that socket won't fill the data of the size it should be.

How can I make a data with fixed size (size I get in string format) and wait for it to get filled with data and then convert in to protobuf?

And is there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after months and days of working on this thing I found the right way to do it and it's not with socket.

To send and receive protobuf to server they have something called BinaryDelimited.

To receive protobuf from server you will use :

```
BinaryDelimited.parse(messageType: ProtoFile.self, from: inputStream )
```

ProtoFile.self is your custom protobuf class that you compiled.

To send protobuf to server you will use :

```
BinaryDelimited.serialize(message: proto, to: outputStream)
```

and to initialize the input and out put and connect it to your server use

```
var inputStream : InputStream!
var outPutStream : OutputStream!

func setupNetworkCommunication() {
        var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           "localhost" as CFString,
                                           port,
                                           &readStream,
                                           &writeStream)

        inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        inputStream.delegate = self
        outputStream.delegate = self

        inputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .common)
        outputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .common)


        inputStream.open()
        outputStream.open()
    }
```